# Internet Explorer session expiring whenever I am running a coded UI script or using record and playback feature

Tags: visual-studio, internet-explorer, visual-studio-2015, coded-ui-tests

Whenever I am running a coded-UI script and opening a website in Internet Explorer through script the IE session expiring
Also when I am manually opening the specific website it is working fine.

Note : This is happening since I have added the website in internet explorer compatibility list and also I cannot remove the website from compatibility as it won't work without compatibility

I am using Visual studio 2015, Internet explorer 11, windows 10

Comment: What's happening if you try to login thru script once the session expires ?

Comment: I am opening a specific url and it's session is getting logged out.

Comment: No I meant, You launch thru Coded Ui ==> Login ==> Session Expires ==> Close Coded UI and try login again manually.. what happens ?

Comment: And, are you saying you open a specific url straight away.. and  it gives you a session expired message ? (Are you expecting to be on the home page when u launch the URL, instead of login page ?)